# Jenkins Deploy WAR/EAR option not available

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins

I am trying to configure the Jenkins to build maven web application to build and deploy war to remote server. I went through the internet and found out that there is a option under Post build Action to deploy war. But I can't find the option. Below is the screenshot. Can any one tell me is there any workaround to build and deploy war?

[image]

Comment: which server do you want to deploy to? jboss 7 or wildfly or tomcat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok.. I found the way. I had to install the **Deploy to container Plugin** from `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the above answer: The following is the path if you want to deploy you war/er to websphere application server.
Jenkins  > manage Jenkins  > Manage Plugins> Deploy Websphere Plugin is to deploy your war/ear file to remote websphere application server.